# Not all ThemeResource recognized correctly on build 16299 but on earlier build are recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

After updating my app to build 16299 (Fall Creators Update) not all ThemeResources in XAML recognized correctly. All resources like SystemBaseXXXXColor or SystemAltXXXXColor (like SystemBaseMediumLowColor) are not recognized. The resource is incompatible type. Anyone else have same problem? Visual studio is up to date as well SDK. If downgrade app back to build 15063 or build 14393 this problem not occur anymore.

Visual example 1:
[image]

Visual example 2:
[image]

UPDATE 2017.11.16

Cannot use any resources after updating from version 15.3.x to 15.4.x. The button is disabled at the propertities and all recourses are "Incompatible type" on XAML editor.

I'm using windows build 16299 and I've set target and min build to 16299. If I select target (and min) 15xxx and under all resources are in use (expect recourses for build 16299). If Target is 16299 and min 15xxx Visual Studio cannot build XAML view at all.

Resources work well on XAML documents that doesn't has any resources from build 16299. But if mixed with non only 16299 resources like "SystemBaseHighColor" ect with resources "SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumRevealBorderBrush" only resources for build 16299 are recognized.

I tried to repair Visual Studio 2017 install and reinstall it but no help. After this I reinstalled Windows 10, updated it and installed Visual Studio...no help. After that I reinstalled Windows without internet connection and installed Visual studio from offline setup...no help! I like to point that operation system install was clean, not any update.

I've got older windows build 15xxx (latest) with Visual Studio 15.3 backup on my drive. Everything works well there. After installed SDK for build 16299 still everything works well expect I cannot build the app for build 16299, of course. 
If I update this window build to latest Windows build the Visual Studio can still find all resources expect it cannot build app because it cannot find SignTool.exe file. If I repair Visual Studio installation, no help. If I update Visual Studio to new build, no help. Reinstall also do not help.

I've tried even the new Preview version, problem still occur. Any help or is the best way to solve the problem is to stick on build 15xxx and keep using it only.

Comment: As you said, I used `SystemBaseMediumLowColor` to test in 16299 project, but I cannot reproduce it. Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and build your project? successful?